# Automatically determine extents for gdal_grid

Tags: raster, gdal, gdal-grid

I am using `gdal_grid` to grid my xyz point data into a raster using the minimum value technique.

```
gdal_grid  -a minimum:radius1=1.0:radius2=1.0:angle=0.0:min_points=0:nodata=0.0 -ot Float32 -of GTiff "C:/INPUT.shp" C:/OUTPUT_RASTER.tif
```

However, with the above code I am getting a very fuzzy/blocky raster with no definition.

Is there any way to automatically determine the extents for `txe and tye` for future datasets that I'd like to create rasters from? Or an alternative approach to get a more defined raster?

Comment: what projection is your raster in 1m seems good, 1 degree is very bad

Comment: @IanTurton It is in EPSG:2157

Comment: `-tr xres yres`

Comment: @user2856 sorry?

Comment: Use `-tr xres yres` and specify the resolution, instead of letting `gdal_grid` use a large  default value.  This doesn't answer the "*automatically determine the extents*" question, but will stop you getting a blocky output if you choose an appropriate pixel size.

Comment: @user2856 is there any way to know what resolution the Arc one is in so that I can use the same for GDAL to compare results? ogrinfo doesn't seem to give the resolution

Comment: ogrinfo is for vector data, gdalinfo will give you the pixel size (resolution).